# read in a tabular file with importing anything

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tabular file(k.tsv) with the following data

```
Name School Year      Course
Nicole UVA  Freshmen   Biology
Jenna GWU   Sophomore  Organic
Brandon VT  Senior     Finance
```

I want to read in this file without importing csv or using csvreader and storing it into a dictionary. How would I do this?

```
my_dict = {}
with open("k.tsv", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items=line.split()
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        my_dict[key] = values
print my_dict
```

I tried this but it's not outputting the data correctly.

Comment: `open()`, `read()`, `close()`. BTW:If you have incorrect data in file then you can get incorrect result. Better show what result you get, and what result you expect.

Comment: your code works perfectly on my computer. Provided you don't have newlines every other line in your file. I get `{'Nicole': ['UVA', 'Freshmen', 'Biology'], 'Jenna': ['GWU', 'Sophomore', 'Organic'], 'Name': ['School', 'Year', 'Course'], 'Brandon': ['VT', 'Senior', 'Finance']}` as expected.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - you right `readlines()` is worse :)

Comment: your code works fine as it is... and "not outputting the data correctly" ? please tell us what you get and what you're expecting. 2 people already wasted their time posting wrong answers because of that (and 2 other people wasted their time downvoting everything that moved :))

Comment: @furas the `with` operator will take care of the closing the file and `f ` is a file iterator. There is nothing wrong with operations being used in the example. Sounds like the input data must be bad.

Comment: I want it so that it's Name: Nicole, School:UVA, Course:Biology and so on

Comment: You can use nested dictionaries...but you will still need a key for the outer most level. You'd end up with something like this `{'Nicole':{'name':'Nicole', 'school':'UVA', 'course':'Biology'}, ... , 'Brandon':{'name':'Brandon', 'school':'VT', 'course':'Finance'}}`. Named tuples are also an option.

Comment: @MS-DDOS I didn't check code. Text `open(), read(), close()` is standard answer for this kind of question. Rest of comment is also standard anwer for this kind of question.

Answer (score -2):

`.split()` splits by whitespace by default, I believe.  So you want `.split(',')` instead, if it really is a csv.

This will give you `{'Nicole': ['UVA', 'Freshmen', 'Biology'], 'Brandon': ['VT', 'Senior', 'Finance'], 'Jenna': ['GWU', 'Sophomore', 'Organic'], 'Name': ['School', 'Year', 'Course']}`  Not sure if this is really what you want though.

Comment: check the input file. It's _not_ a csv.

Comment: ah, I was misled.  Looks like the provided code is fine then.

Comment: Just for the record it shouldn't matter if its comma or tab delimited. If no delimiter is specified Python will determine what it thinks the delimiter is based on consecutive runs of a specific type of whitespace. [See the docs for str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: "If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator". That does **not** apply to commas. Only tab, spaces and other weird "blank" separators (`\xa0`...)